# Hash::check() always returns false

Tags: laravel, hash, passwords

I am trying to check the user input password while logging in and the Hashed password in the database, but it always returns false.

This is the code in the controller Hashing the password

```
$doctor = new doctor;
    $doctor->name = $request->name;
    $doctor->address = $request->address;
    $doctor->email = $request->email;
    $doctor->mobile = $request->mobile;
    $password = Hash::make($request->doctorPassword);
    $doctor->doctorPassword = $password;
```

This is code for validating the password:
      $data = $request->all();

```
    $user = doctor::where('email',$data['doctorUsername'])->first();
    if ($user) {

        if (Hash::check($user->doctorPassword, $data['doctorPassword']))
        {
            return view($this->filePath . '.doctorProfile');
        }
```

}

Always returns false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your argument order is incorrect. You should be adding the plain text version of the password **first** like so:

```
Hash::check($data['doctorPassword'], $user->doctorPassword);
```

Comment: At the moment `$user` is the model instance which has the hashed password. This should be put as the second argument not the first. `$data['doctorPassword']` (which is the request data) should be first.

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is ok here. Just place the hashedPassword `$user->doctorPassword` as the second argument in Hash::check(). Cheers :D

```
$user = doctor::where('email',$data['doctorUsername'])->first();
    if ($user) {

        if (Hash::check($data['doctorPassword'], $user->doctorPassword))
        {
            return view($this->filePath . '.doctorProfile');
        }
```

Please check this link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/hashing